# Defining all elements of a matrix as real numbers

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, assumptions

I want to evaluate the `CholeskyDecomposition` of the following symmetric matrix
 symMat

```
mm = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
symMat = Table[
  If[i >= j, mm[[i, j]], mm[[j, i]]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

It works but as Mathematica works with complex numbers  I have some `Conjugate` commands in the result. How to tel that all parameters are Reals. I have found a nice post which use

```
    $Assumptions = _ ∈ Reals
```

But it has no effect. I have also tried

```
$Assumptions = 
 Subscript[m, 2, 1] \[Element] Reals && 
  Subscript[m, 1, 1] \[Element] Reals &&
  Subscript[m, 3, 1] \[Element] Reals
```

In all cases it doesn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: Did you use any function that uses those Assumptions, like Reduce or Simplify? How about ComplexExpand in this case?

Comment: Your two suggestions doesn't work

Comment: I would appreciate to know why I deserve a downgrading note for a non trivial problem

Comment: Does `$Assumptions = Element[Flatten[mm], Reals]` give what you need?

Comment: kglr following your comment I have tried Assuming[Element[Flatten[symMat], Reals], 
 Refine[CholeskyDecomposition[symMat]]] but it does not have the expected behoviour

Comment: Probably this does not answer your question in general, but `CholeskyDecomposition[symMat] //. Conjugate[x_] -> x` seems to work in this case.

Comment: Thanks Marius. It certainly do the job. But it's the second time we are oblige to do some hack to obtain some thing of MA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just setting `$Assumptions` **does not mean that those assumptions are taken into consideration** during evaluation; you also need to apply a function to your result that is "sensitive" to `$Assumptions`. In practice, these tend to be those functions that take an `Assumptions` option, such as `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Refine`, `FunctionExpand`, `Integrate`...

For instance, this does the job in your case:

```
Simplify[CholeskyDecomposition[symMat], Element[_, Reals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Further details can be found in this tutorial: [Using Assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingAssumptions.html).

Comment: Nice Thanks MarcoB